# Center text in boostrap navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I know there are a lot of posts on the subject of vertical alignment, but I'm still having some issues with it. I have a navbar, which I've changed the height from the default to 64px. Everything in it is resized to that height as well. I've got some drop down menus that look like the following:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Sample Text <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu>
            <h6>Text</h6>
            <ul>
                <!--some li elements-->
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <!--some more li elements-->
</ul>
```

The problem I'm having is that although the a element li's of the top level ul has the height of the navbar and the box for the content is centered vertically (equal padding top and bottom), the text in it is not centered in the box that contains it. Instead it's pushed into the top left corner (not of the a element, but of the box that contains it inside the padding). I've verified this with chrome developer tools. I'm wondering why the text isn't centered vertically and how I can make it that way.

Edit: https://jsfiddle.net/z4c1atdz/ for whatever reason the dropdown isn't working in the fiddle, but that's not really important for the purpose of my issue.

Edit 2:
[image]
The green is padding for the a element. The text of the a element is at the top of the blue box and I want it centered vertically withing the blue box.

Comment: Put ur code in jsFiddle so that anyone can work on it

Comment: Hey eric, your problem is still unclear :( 
how about a fiddle or a pen ;)

Comment: I added a fiddle. I should mention that when I say box, I'm mean the inner most part of the css box model (the part inside the padding) if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried adding more height to the a tag? like this?

```
.navbar-brand {
float: left;
height: 62px;
padding: 21px 17px;
font-size: 18px;
line-height: 20px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/z4c1atdz/11/ like this.

Comment: Yea, in the fiddle, the last css rule sets the height to 64px. The padding centers the box for the content of the a tag li, but the content of the a tag is not centered in the box that holds the content for the a tag. I don't know if box is the right word for what I'm describing. I'm trying to describe the css box model the inner most part inside the padding.

Comment: could you upload an image of what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add padding to the elements inside your navbar to match the new height instead of just changing their height.

If you are using a preprocessor change the height variable of the navbar height. the padding will be automatically calculated.

If you are using plain CSS you will need to manually add extra padding to the element to match the new height. Basically:

```
( navbar height - element height ) / 2
```

As an example you can see the sass mixin extracted from bootstrap's source (_nav-vertical-align.scss mixin).

```
// Navbar vertical align
//
// Vertically center elements in the navbar.
// Example: an element has a height of 30px, so write out `.navbar-vertical-align(30px);` to calculate the appropriate top margin.

@mixin navbar-vertical-align($element-height) {
    margin-top: (($navbar-height - $element-height) / 2);
    margin-bottom: (($navbar-height - $element-height) / 2);
}
```

This is used for the navbar buttons, etc...

Comment: The element already has the height of the navbar, and padding to center the element vertically within the navbar, that's not the problem. The issue is that, if you look at the picture, the text isn't centered vertically withing the blue box. That blue box is contains the content of the a element and the green around it is the padding for the a element.

Comment: Yeah, that's because you're setting the height on the elements, you should instead leave the elements with their default height and change their padding. If you have text inside an element with set height it will be at the top unless you use flex box... If you notice bootstrap centres the elements inside the navbar using padding or margin